# jQuery .tap event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why the jQuery tap event isn't even getting a respond when I test it. I put in an alert and I haven't gotten it to pop up at all. My code looks like this:

```
var calendarOpen = false;

$('.calendar').on("tap", function () {
alert('1'); 
    if (calendarOpen == false) {
        $('.login-body').animate({left: '90%'}, 300);
        $('.calendar-body').animate({right: '10%'}, 300);
        calendarOpen = true;
    } else {
        $('.login-body').animate({left: '0px'}, 300);
        $('.calendar-body').animate({right: '50%'}, 300);
        calendarOpen = false;
    }
});
```

I have the script and css pages attached and I've checked for any typos. I copied the jQuery documentation and I'm still having problems. Thanks for the help.

These are my included scripts and the code provided above is under main.js.

```
<script src=http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js></script>
<script src=http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: You declare the library of Jquery or this script stay inside `<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { `  ???

Comment: Are you referring to the jQuery Mobile `tap` event (and including the library)? http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Comment: It's either the native [touch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events) events, or you'll need to add something more than jQuery, like jQ mobile.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I did include both jquery and jquery-mobile.

Comment: @user2666291 What version of jQuery are you using? Have you watched your browser's console to check for any unexpected exceptions? Where is the code you provided being executed? Is the `.calendar` elements rendered/ready? A simple example works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qkhZz/

Comment: I added included scripts up top. There shouldn't be anything unexpected going on. I was using an .on('click') before and everything was working great but I figured I would test out the tap event on mobile to hopefully get rid of the 300ms delay and I was going to end up using some of the swiping as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load your JS files in this order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Wow thank you. I knew it was going to be something stupidly simple like that.